# What we pass 0 In date functions As Arguments for calculation of Start Date,End Date what is the explanation for that argument?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

here  like these queries,
I.e: here is First date of year is calculated ,

```
select DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

and here 0 are used,what is the explanation for that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That's product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 2):

You mean "Why", obviously.

0 is an arbitrary date which is easy to write, I think 1st January 1753. It does not matter in the all-too-common dateadd(datediff()) formula, ANY date/time would be just as good if put in both the dateadd's and the datediff's arguments. But, 0 is easy to write, plus everyone is doing the same and it creates some comfort seeing it and understanding it.

The way dateadd-datediff works is this: eg in your query

```
DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

, you want the first moment of the year of getdate(). How do you do this? You ask how many years have passed, from 1st January 1753, to getdate(3 July 2018), which results in 265. You then add that number(265) of years to 1st January 1753. Because you only added the years, and not months, days, hours etc you will get 1/1/2018 00:00:00.